# Insert string in a class in a vue js component

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello i have a vue component where i loop in a list of countries like that :

```
<div v-for="i in pays" :key="i.id">
  {{i.name}}
  <span class="flag-icon-gr"></span>
```

And i would like to change the end of the flag-icon with the according label i receive from my loop. For example i would like to have flag-icon-fr if the country is france. Is there a proper way to do that ?

ps: im using nuxt but i guess it is the same for a normal vue js component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the class dynamically using something like this:

```
<span :class=:icon="'fa-flag' + i.name"></span>
```

Comment: exactly what i needed !